# Google maps v3 API markers dissapears when closing its InfoWindow (InfoBubble)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am pretty new to JavaScript and the google maps API. I cannot figure out what is wrong.

The InfoWindow is actually a class I found "InfoBubble". 
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/

**Here is the situation:**

```
1. I create my map and add a 'click' event. The event creates Markers. 
2. I create one global infoWindow.
3. I click the map, a Marker appears.
4. I click the map, a Marker appears.
5. I click the map, a Marker appears. Step 3-5 can be repeated lots and lots.
6. I click marker number X 
  6.1. An infoWindow pops up.
7. I click marker number Y 
  7.1. The infoWindow is closed. (.close())
  7.2. Its content and position is changed
  7.3. It is opened on the new position (.open(map,marker))
  7.4. Also Marker number X is removed.
```

**Try it yourself:** http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6084360/test/index.html

Why is step 7.4. happening? After it has happened I can click markers however I feel like without anything disappearing. **WHY?**

I have tried debugging somewhat via Google Chrome but after I do step **7.3** it takes me into some minified code and I get lost.

Here is the line which removes the marker. I have no idea why it removes it or how to know where to start.

```
R.addDomListenerOnce=function(a,b,c,d){var e=R[yc](a,b,function(){e[wb]();return c[Cc](this,arguments)},d);return e};R.R=function(a,b,c,d){c=cf(c,d);return R[yc](a,b,c)};function cf(a,b){return function(c){return b[oc](a,c,this)}}R.bind=function(a,b,c,d){return R[G](a,b,P(c,d))};R.addListenerOnce=function(a,b,c){var d=R[G](a,b,function(){d[wb]();return c[Cc](this,arguments)});return d};R.forward=function(a,b,c){return R[G](a,b,df(b,c))};R.ua=function(a,b,c,d){return R[yc](a,b,df(b,c,!d))};
```

My code:

```
    var times = 0;
    var treasureLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(62.05350309096103, 15.373047874999997);
    var map, infoBubble = null;

    function initialize() 
    {   
        // Create the actual map.
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
            {
              zoom:         4,
              center:       new google.maps.LatLng(62.05350309096103, 15.373047874999997),
              mapTypeId:    google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
        );

        infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
            disableAutoPan: true
        });

        // Add an eventlistener to the map.
        google.maps.event.addListener
        (
            map, 
            'click', 
            function(ev)
            {
                addMarker(ev);
            }
        );              
    }

    function addMarker(ev)
    {
        // Get the distance.
        var distance = getDistance( ev.latLng , treasureLocation );

        // Skriv ut vart man klickade.
        document.getElementById("click_info").innerHTML = "Du klickade " + distance + " ifrån skatten, försök igen!";

        // Create a marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:   ev.latLng,
            map:        map,
            clickable:  true,
            title:      "Härifån är det bara " + distance + " till skatten!",
            icon:       "shovel.png"
        });

        // Hook the click on the created marker to show the created popup
        google.maps.event.addListener
        (
            marker,
            'click',
            function(ev)
            {
                if( infoBubble != null ){infoBubble.close();}
                infoBubble.setContent(marker.title);
                infoBubble.setPosition(marker.position);
                infoBubble.open(map, marker);
            }
        );

    }
```

Comment: Well, i can't rly explain why, but i found out that, `infoBubble.setPosition(marker.position);` causes the problem for me. If you comment it out or delete, the first marker won't disappear (also clicking again on same wont change bubble content, which happened too). Well, you assign the place where it should open anyway using `infoBubble.open(map, marker);` so i guess you wont need it :) Try it and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks! I think that line moved the marker to the second-clicked-marker. I saw one of my markers texts way off where it should have been, but I just brushed it off and went along.

Anyway, thanks! You should put it as an 'answer' so I can upvote and 'accept' and maybe more people will see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really explain why but seems like `infoBubble.setPosition(marker.position);` is causing trouble. Just Delete it. You are using `infoBubble.open(map, marker);` to define bubble position, so you don't rly need it.